# Find vector $\vec{c}$ from following info

Tags: vectors

Given $2$ unit vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ such that, the angle between them is $\arccos\tfrac{1}{4}$. If $\vec{c}$ vector is a vector in plane of $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ vectors, such that magnitude of vector $\vec{c}$ equals $4$, and $\vec{c}×\vec{b}=2\vec{a}×\vec{b}$, find vector $\vec{c}$. I tried to interpret the situation geometrically, I think the answer might be $2\vec{a}$ vector if I prove $\vec{c}$ vector $-\vec{2a}$ vector isnt parallel/antiparallel to $\vec{b}$ vector. I did this geometrically but how do I do this the other way?

Comment: I think we need something else in the given.

Comment: I provided all info given in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be $\vec c=2\vec a$ since $4=|\vec c|=|2\vec a|=2$.

**Method 1: geometrically**

Use $|\vec x\times \vec y|=|\vec x||\vec y||\sin \theta|$, where $\theta$ is the angle between vectors. You can apply it then to $\vec c\times \vec b=2\vec a\times \vec b$ and say that the angle between $\vec c$ and $\vec b$, say $\theta_{bc}$ obeys $$|4\sin\theta_{bc}|=|2\sin\theta_{ab}|=2\sin\left(\arccos\frac{1}{4}\right)$$ or $$|\sin\theta_{bc}|=\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(\arccos\frac{1}{4}\right)$$ In addition, to preserve the orientation of $\vec c\times \vec b$, the vector $\vec c$ has to be on the same side of $\vec b$ as $\vec a$. You should get two solutions $$\theta_{bc}=\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(\arccos\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)$$ and the complement.

**Method 2: analytically**

Any vector in the $ab$ plane can be written as a linear combination of $\vec a$ and $\vec b$. In particular $\vec c=\alpha\vec a+\beta\vec b$. You have two equations:
$$\vec c\cdot\vec c=16=\alpha^2+\beta^2+2\alpha\beta\cos\theta_{ab}=\alpha^2+\beta^2+\frac{1}{2}\alpha\beta$$
and the other equation is $$ \vec c\times \vec b=(\alpha\vec a+\beta\vec b)\times\vec b=\alpha \vec a \times\vec b=2\vec a\times \vec b$$
So $\alpha=2$. Then $16=2^2+\beta^2+\beta$, with solutions $\beta=3$ and $\beta=-4$. So $\vec c=2\vec a+3\vec b$ or $\vec c=2\vec a-4\vec b$

Comment: Oh thanks, which book do you prefer for vectors?

Comment: I don't have a good reference for vectors. All these formulas are physics related. See for example http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vecm.html#vecmh